# i need to find a integer data in arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `Arraylist`. If user enter the same number secondly I want to show to user. For this I need to find `Arraylist` have it or not.

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Would you like to share anything that you have tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at ArrayList API before asking such a question. It's trivial to notice ArrayList class has a contains() method from its definition.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you are checking to see if some value is stored in an `ArrayList` you can use the `contains()` method, this will return `true` if the object is in the list, `false` otherwise.

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

intList.add(5);
intList.add(7);
intList.add(3);
intList.add(-2);

intList.contains(-1); //returns false
intList.contains(3); //returns true
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use [`ArrayList.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) to check if the element is in the `ArrayList` or not.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have not.  But here's my best guess:

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 4, -5, 44 );
int userValue = 44;
if (!values.contains(userValue)) {
    values.add(userValue);
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write `if (!values.contains(userValue))`?

Comment: I'm not looking to "boost my rep," whatever that's supposed to mean. I'm just looking to help people reading this question in the future, since people *do* read old questions.

Comment: Code's not wrong.  Saves one line.  Who'd you help?

Comment: Really not sure why you're getting so worked up about this, but if you really want me to reply: Unless you're planning to reuse `containsUserValue` somewhere else, declaring a boolean like this is pointless and impedes readability, since it's yet another variable for the reader to keep track. Don't worry, it's a common stylistic error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to check if an array list already contains and integer value. If so, you could use ArrayList.contains().

Sample code here:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
int x = 4, y = 7;
int z = x;

list.add(x);

//List contains the value 4, which is the value stored in z
//Program will output "List contains 4"
if(list.contains(z))
{
    System.out.printf("List contains %d\n", z);
}
else
{
    System.out.printf("List does not contain %d\n", z);
}

//List contains the value 7, which is the value stored in y
//Program will output "List does not contain 7"   
if(list.contains(y))
{
    System.out.printf("List contains %d\n", y);
}
else
{
    System.out.printf("List does not contain %d\n", y);
}
```