# ArrayList<int[]> containing a value

Tags: java

if i have an `ArrayList<int[]>` example and I want to check if {2,4} is in it how would I do this?

```
exaple.contains({2,4}); //doesn't work
```

and

```
exaple.contains(2,4); //doesn't work either
```

what is wrong with the code?

Comment: `exaple.contains(new int[]{2,4});` test it.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno this will not work since the comparision will be on addresses and not on the content

Comment: Syntactically, `.contains(new int[]{2,4})` would be correct. However, it wouldn't, since that new array won't be equal to any array in the list.

Comment: @giorashc Yup, i said only how to fix the errors. Otherwise I would have posted a reply

Answer (score 11):

Arrays don't override the `Object.equals()` method (that `ArrayList.contains()` uses to compare objects). So an array is only equal to itself. You'll have to loop through the list and compare each element with your array using `Arrays.equals()`.

What I suspect, though, is that you shouldn't have a `List<int[]>`, but a `List<Coordinate>`. The Coordinate class could then override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, and you would be able to use

```
example.contains(new Coordinate(2, 4))
```

You could also use a `List<List<Integer>>`, but if what I suspect is true (i.e. you're using arrays to hold two coordinates that should be in class), then go with the custom Coordinate class.

Comment: @JB Nizet Great answer, very well explained!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you did it properly, ie:

```
int[] vals = {2, 4};

exaple.contains(vals);
```

You would not return true, because the `contains` method will use the `equals` method. Unless you have overridden the `equals` method, then this will always resolve to `false`, unless you pass in the *exact same array*.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this. And please post a bit of you're code.

[i need to find a integer data in arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342859/i-need-to-find-a-integer-data-in-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

The `contains()` method checks, if `ArrayList` contains a specific object, it doesn't concern itself with the values inside an object. In other words, if you instantiate two {2,4} arrays, it will be two different objects and `contains()` method will diferentiate between them.

What you need to do is either override the `contains()` method to look on the *content* of arrays, instead of only the *reference*, or you can drop the `contains()` method completely and check it by hand.