# Check whether List<Integer> is equal to an int

Tags: java, arraylist, int

This is some of my current code:

Class `usedCoords` contains:

```
public List<Integer> USEDX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

`main` function contains:

```
if(fX % gridX == 0 && fZ % gridZ == 0 && ALPHA != 0 && usedcoords.USEDX == fX) { }
```

Note I also done: `usedCoords usedcoords = new usedCoords();`, that is why I named it usedcoords.

My main task is that I want to make the `usedcoords.USEDX == fX` possible. Currently I will get an error because `fX is an integer`. `USEDX` has integers as well so how do check that the any integer in `USEDX` is equal to `fX`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342859/i-need-to-find-a-integer-data-in-arraylist   you could check this question too

Comment: Couldn't find it because I didn't know how to phrase it! Lol

Comment: You should rename the title of the question, which is quite confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`List#contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) -- and it's more readable and conventional not to have variable names start with an uppercase unless they are constants:

```
if (fX % gridX == 0 && fZ % gridZ == 0 && alpha != 0 && usedcoords.usedX.contains(fX)) {
   ...
}
```

The `int` variable `fX` will be automatically boxed into the `Integer` type by the compiler.

Comment: Worked well however I remembered fX was a float but I fixed it by converting (int)fX

Comment: In this case you may lose precision (both `3.0` and `3.3` will be matched to a `3` in the list). Ideally you should have a `List<Float>`.

Comment: True point however I have also made sure that it is divisible by 4 (so it will always be whole) I just had to keep them as floats because I wanted to make it easier with Vector3f(s)

Answer (score 3):

> USEDX has integers as well so how do check that the any integer in USEDX is equal to fX?

By calling [`List.contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) which *returns `true` if this list contains the specified element.* Something like,

```
if (USEDX.contains(fx)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency-sake, you may use `Hashtable<Integer>` instead of `List` because it requires *O(1)* (constant) time to search for a value.